# Different behavior with break point and without breakpoint in junit by Selenium Chrome Driver

Tags: angular, selenium, debugging, junit, selenium-chromedriver

I want to fill sign in page, then navigate to a custom form with selenium.
When I make a break point, session is OK. when I toggle it off, session will be cleared. Angular authentication navigates to login page.

If I toggle the break point on, the page navigates to "http://localhost:5000/ui/portal/sys/cbank/bank-accounts/add" (the session is saved).
when I toggle it off: The browser navigates to "http://localhost:5000/ui/portal/access/signin", because the session is cleared out and angular can not find it authorised.

```java
@Test
    public void whenOpenningThePageTheGridShouldBeFilledWithData() {
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("http://localhost:5000/ui/portal/user/landing");
        WebElement userName = driver.findElement(By.name("username"));
        WebElement password = driver.findElement(By.name("password"));
        WebElement captcha = driver.findElement(By.name("captcha"));
        userName.clear();
        password.clear();
        captcha.clear();
        userName.sendKeys("admin");
        password.sendKeys("admin");
        captcha.sendKeys("1111111111111"); // fake captcha
        driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("[type='submit']")).click();
        /*breakpoint*/driver.navigate().to("http://localhost:5000/ui/portal/sys/cbank/bank-accounts/add");
    }
```

As I said, I expect the test to navigate to "add" page, but it does not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The test should wait for the finishing of login process.
I added a  `Thread.sleep(1000);`  inside the code:

```
driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.get("http://localhost:5000/ui/portal/user/landing");
WebElement userName = driver.findElement(By.name("username"));
WebElement password = driver.findElement(By.name("password"));
WebElement captcha = driver.findElement(By.name("captcha"));
userName.clear();
password.clear();
captcha.clear();
userName.sendKeys("admin");
password.sendKeys("admin");
captcha.sendKeys("1111111111111");
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("[type='submit']")).click();
Thread.sleep(1000);
driver.get("http://localhost:5000/ui/a-private-page");
```